# Silverlight webcam API throwing strange error

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, webcam

I am trying to show my webcam using VideoBrush on rectangle. However, i am facing this weird issue :-

```
External component has thrown an exception.

   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CaptureGraph_GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevicesNative(IntPtr pContext, Int32& typeIndex, CValue& DeviceCollection)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CaptureGraph_GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices()
   at System.Windows.Media.CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice()
   at System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource..ctor()
   at FMT.Client.Views.ChildWindows.Webcam.Webcam_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

I then right clicked on Silverlight application, went into configuration and then into Mic/Webcam tab. I have my webcam selected there and i can see my webcam fine when i am in that dialog. Here is my code :-

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System;

namespace FMT.Client.Views.ChildWindows
{
    public partial class Webcam : ChildWindow
    {
        private CaptureSource _source;
        private CaptureDevice _webcam;
        private VideoBrush _webcamBrush;
        private ImageBrush _capturedImage;

        public Webcam()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += Webcam_Loaded;
        }

        void Webcam_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices().Count <= 0)
                //{
                //    ErrorWindow window = new ErrorWindow("Error","Please check the default webcam in the Silverlight config. You can specify the video and audio devices that are used by default with the Silverlight Configuration. Just press the right mouse button over the application, click Silverlight in the context menu and select the  Webcam / Mic tab to set them.");
                //    window.Show();
                //    this.DialogResult = false;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                    _source = new CaptureSource();
                    _source.CaptureImageCompleted += _source_CaptureImageCompleted;
                    _source.CaptureFailed += _source_CaptureFailed;
                    _webcam = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();
                    if (_webcam != null)
                    {
                        _source.VideoCaptureDevice = (VideoCaptureDevice)_webcam;
                        _webcamBrush = new VideoBrush();
                        _webcamBrush.SetSource(_source);
                        capturedRect.Fill = _webcamBrush;
                        _capturedImage = new ImageBrush();
                        RequestAccess();
                    }
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorWindow window = new ErrorWindow(ex);
                window.Show();
                this.DialogResult = false;
            }
        }

        void RequestAccess()
        {
            if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess() && _source.VideoCaptureDevice != null)
            {
                _source.Start();
            }
            else
                this.DialogResult = false;
        }

        void _source_CaptureFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ErrorWindow window = new ErrorWindow(e.ErrorException);
            window.Show();
        }

        void _source_CaptureImageCompleted(object sender, CaptureImageCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Result != null)
                _capturedImage.ImageSource = e.Result;
        }

        private void hypCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_source.VideoCaptureDevice != null &&
               _source.State == CaptureState.Started)
            {
                _source.CaptureImageAsync();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea, why does the execution fails while calling the constructor of CaptureSource?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does `CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices().Count` return? Also, try it outside of debugger (some Cam drivers really do not like debuggers).

Comment: @Jaroslav Jandek :- Yes now it works. Another change that was needed was the RequestAccess function has to be called on button click only. Even though the child window itself is opening on button_click. But the RequestAccess has to further called from some other button else CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess() will silently fail. It won't work in loaded event. That's why all the examples i have seen so far have a start button in the form :-). It may be yet another stupid Microsoft restriction.

Comment: @Kar Cheng: that feature actually makes sense. I would not want SL apps to silently use my cam. If it were allowed everywhere, while you could auto-pop a request, it could still be used to spamming the user...

Comment: @Jaroslav Jandek :- How?? CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess() is meant for taking the permission of the user. Without user's permission SL can't silently use cam. SL only can when the user specifically clicks on OK button. This restriction means even for "taking the permission of the user for using webcam, we need to have user initiated action" which is not proper according to me.

Comment: @Kar Cheng: read the whole comment please, I have stated why. Let me reiterate: Without user interaction, program could either silently use cam or (in current implementation) spam the user with confirmation windows. That is IMHO unacceptable.

Comment: No developer would like this sort of silly restrictions. Even if the user is so annoyed he should close the application. I believe he can do that under any circumstances. Even in IsolatedStorage in Silverlight i have faced several issues due to this user initiated action thing. What would you do when you have to store few images on the client side in IsolatedStorage? Say the a button is pressed and on that a OpenFileDialog is opened and users selects 5 images of 500 kb each. After dialog is closed, since the limit of IsolatedStorage is only 1 MB,

Comment: he won't be able to store all the images. So you may think of calling IncreaseQuotaTo method of IsolatedStorage. But this method also has this stupid restriction that it must be a user initiated action (Also the time limit where user initiated action is acceptable is roughly 1 second.) and 1 second is already over by the time the user finds and selects the images in openfiledialog your method call will fail. What would you do at this time? Popup an another popup and ask the user saying, please click on this button so we can popup yet another popup of requesting to increase quota?

Comment: IMHO because of this silly restriction you are likely to put the user in a jungle of popups by asking him to click here and there so that SL can count it as user initiated action and then developer's code will work.

Comment: Anyways, back to my original question. Here also i am facing same issue. I already have a start button on my form which upon clicking opens a childwindow (And which in my opinion is a user initiated action). So why am i not able to call CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess() in loaded event? Already the child window opens upon a user initiated action. Why put yet another button asking the user to please click it, so SL can count it as user initiated action and then it can show popup for requesting webcam? I think Microsoft has put over restriction on SL after the failure of ActiveX.

Comment: @Kar Cheng: from the user's perspective I like the feature. It's more work from the programmer's perspective, though...
IIRC the action must be called when the user-initiated action (button click) is still in scope and the first thing on the current call stack => put it directly in the event handler and it should work.

Comment: Yeah that works. I had encapsulated all of the logic for webcam in the childwindow. But now i have to put this thing capturedevice thing in the caller code and copy and paste this stuff from wherever i use this window in my project.

Comment: @Kar Cheng: Create one Requestin event handler and add to button events wherever you need (if possible).